# XSLT 2.0 - Sort a for-each-group with a dynamically selected group-by

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following data:

```
<row>
  <category>1</category>
  <account>000</account>
  <description>000-description</description>
  <amount>1000</amount>
  <budget>1500</budget>
</row>
 . . . 
<row>
  <category>9</category>
  <account>999</account>
  <description>999-description</description>
  <amount>1000</amount>
  <budget>1500</budget>
</row>
```

I have a template that allows the user to pass the data in as `$group` and a string in as `$group_by`. `$group_by` variable is fed into a `for-each-group` and is used as a string representation of the node name to group off of:

```
<xsl:template name="acct-row">
  <xsl:param name="group"/>
  <xsl:param name="group_by"/>
       <xsl:for-each-group select="$group" group-by="*[local-name() = $group_by]">
        . . . 
       </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

I'd like to use this same `group_by` variable inside of the `for-each-group` body to sort the elements like so:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="$group" group-by="*[local-name() = $group_by]">
  <xsl:sort select="*[local-name() = $group_by]"/>
  . . .
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
oracle.xdo11g.xslt.XSLOtherElements cannot be cast to oracle.xdo11g.xslt.XSLSort
```

I've also tried using `current-grouping-key()` inside of the `xsl:sort`, but alas that gives me the same error.

I know that I could manually call a specific element to sort off of, but I'd like for this to be dynamic.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem using your description: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93wniTY. Perhaps it's an issue with your XSLT processor?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hmm. That would not surprise me. I also tried to use an `if` statement inside the sort's select attribute to dynamically pick either "category" or "account". Still get the same error. Might have to resort to sorting the data in SQL beforehand.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a structure of `xsl:choose` and prepare a hard-coded `xsl:sort` instruction for each possible selection.

Comment: Can you show us where/how exactly you pass the parameter in? Have you tried to add `as` attributes for the type (e.g. `<xsl:param name="group_by" as="xs:string"/>`, `<xsl:with-param name="group_by" as="xs:string">category</xsl:with-param>`)? I am only throwing in some options, I don't know why/where `oracle.xdo11g.xslt` fails.

Comment: Looks like you're using the XSLT processor from Oracle's XDK. IIRC they implemented most of XSLT 2.0 but then abandoned further development after the Sun acquisition. You're seeing what's clearly an internal error within the XSLT processor.

Comment: @MartinHonnen We've tried using both with and without the `as="xs:string"` specifier. Still fails. Appreciate the suggestion!

@MichaelKay Glad you could assist! Yes, Oracle/Sun did not fully implement the XSLT 2.0 specification. Of course this makes development on their platform pretty confusing and laborious at times.